# Commit() in psycopg2 seems to be not executed

Tags: python, postgresql, cmd, psycopg2

And so I have this Python file (**dosql.py**):

```
import sys
import psycopg2

class doSql(object):
    #attributes
    _cxn = ""
    _cur = ""
    errmsg ="" 
    #methods
    def __init__(self): #constructor
        self._cxn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='postgres' password='4scoreand7yearsago' host='127.0.0.1' port='5432'")
        self._cur = self._cxn.cursor()

    def __del__(self): #destructor
        self._cur.close()
        self._cxn.close()

    def execqry(self, sql, apply_):
        rows = []
        try:
            self._cur.execute(sql)
            rows = self._cur.fetchall()
        if apply_:
                self._cxn.commit()
            if self._cur.rowcount == 0:
                rows.append(['None'])
        except:
            #errmsg = sys.exc_type + ":" + sys.exc_value 
            errmsg =  str(sys.exc_info()[1])
            rows.append([errmsg])
        return rows
```

In pgAdmin through the Query Tool, I already have a table with the predefined data in the database '**postgres**'.

```
CREATE TABLE misc (
     id int primary key,
     col1 text,
     col2 text
);

INSERT INTO misc VALUES (1, 'yes', 'i', 'entered');
```

To which in the cmd, I try to execute inside the Python interpreter (with respect to the directory of the file):

```
>>> execfile('dosql.py')
>>> a = doSql()
>>> i = a.execqry("SELECT * FROM misc", False)
>>> print i
[(1, 'yes', 'i', 'entered')]
>>> f = a.execqry("INSERT INTO misc VALUES (2, 'please', 'just', 'enter')", True)[0][0]
>>> print f
no results to fetch
>>> g = a.execqry("SELECT * FROM misc", False)
>>> print g
[(1, 'yes', 'i', 'entered'), (2, 'please', 'just', 'enter')]
```

But when I go check pgAdmin and browse the table, **it doesn't update to 2 rows**, still only has 1, (the [1, 'yes', 'i', 'entered'] data).

Does this mean that the **self._cxn.commit()** didn't work? Also when I try to redo the whole process again and then initialize the destructor through **del a**, still to no avail, no updated table.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code pass `False` for `apply_` parameter; which result no `commit` call.

```
a.execqry("INSERT INTO ......", False)
                                ^^^^^
```

Try the code with `True` argument.

Comment: Shouldn't the 

`f = a.execqry("INSERT INTO misc VALUES (2, 'please', 'just', 'enter')", True)[0][0]`

be the only one with True? Because SELECT should not affect the database from what I understood, that's why it must be False.

Comment: But lemme try. Huehue.

Comment: It did work! Thanks @falsetru! But I have a question, why do I have to commit() the 2nd time around, in SELECT, when I already committed in the INSERT?

Comment: @user3458391, Yes, you're right. `commit` for `SELECT` is not required .